# How to check module enable or not from system advance tab in xml

Tags: layout, magento-1, configuration

I am adding a tab in product page in admin. I want to check module is enable or not before adding tab from xml.

`System -> Configuration -> Advanced`

Only in case of module enable then we want to add some xml to include. but in case of writing `ifconfig` we are getting true if module enable.

is there any else condition for that ?

Answer (score 1):

System -> Configuration -> Advanced is just for showing the module output or not. Even "disable" module on thispage, the module still run on background.

To truly disable a module, you should go to app/etc/modules/Module_Name.xml and set active to false. So that:

```
<active>false</active>
```

If you want to add dependency inside a module, you can add the following code:

```
<depends>
      <Module_Name />
</depends>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right way to disable any module from xml file.
You need to change in app/etc/modules/module_name.xml
change "true" to "false" in active tag.

Comment: <active>true</active>  to  <active>false</active>

Answer (score 0):

Using your tab interface *Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface* allows you to control the display via the method *canShowTab*.

```
public function canShowTab()
{
    return Mage::helper('Core')->isModuleEnabled('Vendor_Module');
}
```

Comment: How we call this method in xml to check module enable or not so that I can include the file on that basis ?